# Conversão de HTACCESS em WEB.CONFIG - AZURE

Tags: php, htaccess, microsoft-azure, web.config, hospedagem

tudo bem?

Seguinte, comecei a utilizar a hospedagem da Azure para criar meu site em Wordpress, agora surgiu a necessidade de uma aplicação em uma subpasta em MVC, hoje tenho um arquivo **.htaccess** que faz a famosa url amigável e também utilizo rotas, gostaria de uma ajuda para converter o mesmo.

Abaixo tenho meu códigodo **htaccess** e meu **web.config**.

**Esquema de pasta:**

./ SITE EM WORDPRESS

./ SITE EM WORDPRESS / MINHA APLICAÇÃO

**Arquivo: .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Arquivo: web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://sitexwebapp.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Obrigado, foi alterado.